# Control Raspberry Pi to control an Arduino over Apache

Tags: python, arduino, pi-zero-w, apache-httpd

I want to control a Raspberry pi to control an arduino which is controlled by a webpage hosted by apache. I do not know how I would attempt this and if it is even possible. Can anyone please guide me in the right direction to do this. I want to press a button and it tells the pi to send an I2C signal to the Arduino to start the motor while the button is pressed.

Comment: Divide your problem into subproblems and then try to find an answer for each of them. For example:
1. Hosting Apache website on Raspberry Pi
2. Raspberry Pi and Arduino connection
BTW why not starting the motor directly from RPi?

Comment: Are you using `pigpiod` ?

Comment: @Mark I know I am going to start the connection between the 2 via I2C, but I want to know how I can control that I2C connection from Apache. I’m not doing it from the Pi because the PWM on the pi isn’t great and I plan to do more in the future with this project.

Comment: @Guy.D What is pigpiod?

Comment: @EpicGamer_1 "pigpio is a library for the Raspberry which allows control of the General Purpose Input Outputs (GPIO).  pigpio works on all versions of the Pi. Download." you cant find it here: http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/

Comment: @EpicGamer_1how do you plan to control Arduino? wired ? over LAN ( remotely ) ?

Comment: @Guy.D I am using the GPIO pins on the Pi to communicate via I2C to the Arduino

Comment: @EpicGamer_1I can't understand what is the functionality of Arduino if it connected wirely to Pi ? can't you commence I2C directly from Pi ?

Comment: @Guy.D I am planning it this way: connect the Pi to the Arduino via GPIO, have the Arduino control motors as i am going to add much more in the future. I want to control the raspberry pi to send a signal to move the motor via a web interface

Comment: @EpicGamer_1 Please see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=30882

Comment: @EpicGamer_1- OK. why not using Pi only to control the motor ? what is the necessity of Arduino

Comment: You can do this using programming language, with any web server and any OS. The answers would be speculative and incomplete. The general answer to your question is Yes. The right direction, choose an OS, choose a programming language. I suggest Rasbpian and Python, or Windows IoT and C# - Good luck soldier!

Comment: @Guy.D I am using the Arduino because it’s PWM is better than that of the Pi and I am planning on connecting more things as well

Comment: @ppumkin I plan to use python for the I2C connection. Is there any way that could connect to the web server to run it when a button is pressed and too when the button isn’t pressed

Comment: Yes, we have a plethora of choices to do this. And Python it self can be the webserver. You can use NodeJS, CGI (as suggested below), C# Core2 WebApi/Sockets, and it goes on and on. I would suggest sticking with Python. Learn how to make a python server,with webapi, its easy. Then you call the API endpoitns that do things on the Pi

Comment: @ppumkin that was my initial intention. I now do plan to go with python. I will be able to create buttons and all?

Comment: Yes, by using HTML and CSS. Buttons then use AJAX to call WebAPI

Comment: @ppumkin Thank you, I will look into this and start soon!

Comment: @ppumkin I dont know how to keep the function running while the button is clicked. Can I still use AJAX for it?

Comment: Sure. You can use onDown and onUp events of the button and control the state on the server. This means sending one request for down and another on up.  To make it more robust you can resend on down after checking if the button is still on down and keep sending requests evey second saying it is still onDown until you get an onUp event or the server timesOut (in case you loose connection with client) Or you can also use websockets to stream data between clients.

Answer (score 0):

You need [cgi](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html), cgi are scripts or programs run by server. There are plenty of [example](https://code-maven.com/set-up-cgi-with-apache)

You can have a cgi script on server called by web page via forms to start/stop your motor.

You can develop cgi in python, bash, c ...

Comment: So I could use CGI to turn a motor on when a button is pressed by it sending an I2C signal to the Arduino and turn it off when it isn’t pressed. All in python and Apache?

Comment: Yes. I make something close to what you want to do (I'm using webpage on mobile phone to open/close portal and garage door) [see](https://ouiaremakers.com/posts/tutoriel-diy-sesame-ouvre-toi) You can too  use an Arduino Yun if your raspberry pi is only used as web server , the Arduino Yun can do the job, but with raspberry pi it is possible too.

Answer (score 0):

Use these:

Control rapsberry using PHP.

Use python to execute scripts over i2c

conenct i2c to arduino.

make all arduinos on i2c bus as slave mode to receive a fixed range of bytes.

use these byte data to interpret and pefrom action in arduino using C